# Designing polymorphic API

Tags: elm

I have a notion of a Scale which converts between an input domain and an output range. There are several types of scales however; each supports a subset of possible operations and stores a slightly different range.

For example:

A `Continuous` Scale (`Scale (Float, Float) (Float, Float)`) which has the domain `(Float, Float)` and the range `(Float, Float)` supports:

- `convert : Continuous -> Float -> Float` convert a value from the domain to the range.
- `invert : Continuous -> Float -> Float` convert a value from the range back to the domain.
- `domain : Continuous -> (Float, Float)` return the domain.
- `ticks : Continuous -> List Float` returns values suitable for drawing on an Axis.

An `Sequential` scale has a domain of `(Float, Float)` and a function from `Float -> a`, it generally makes not much sense to store the range.

- `convert : Sequential a -> Float -> a` convert a value from the domain to the range.
- `domain : Sequential a -> (Float, Float)` return the domain.

A `Quantile` scale maps a sampled input domain (`List Float`) to a discrete range (`List a`). The domain is considered continuous; however, the domain is specified as a discrete set of sample values.

- `convert : Quantile a -> Float -> a` convert a value from the domain to the range.
- `invertExtent : Quantile a -> a -> (Float, Float)` returns an extent from the domain corresponding to the range.

If the above example doesn't make much sense, don't worry. The main point is that there are several types of objects that share some logical operations, but not all. Some operations are only shared by some but not all types. Some operations only have "special" behavior for some types, but could be defaulted to a sensible fallback (i.e. `identity`) for the others, in other cases there is no sensible implementation. It is also highly useful to be able to specify generic algorithms over all possible scales, or over all scales supporting a particular operation.

How would I design an API like this in Elm?

---

Some bad ideas I had so far:

- Check if an implementation is supported, otherwise throw a runtime error. Yuck.
- Wrap these in a hierarchy of modules, where the caller needs to know what level of wrapping/unwrapping they need to do to call the appropriate method. This seems exceedingly ugly for the caller and a very difficult API to use. Also won't be able to handle all cases.
- Have a type with something like `Scale supportsOp1 supportsOp2 supportsOp3` where each of those type variables can have either the type of `SupportsOp` or `Doesnt`. Then I can have a function of e.g. `op1 : Scale SupportsOp a b -> c`. This does the trick, but the type annotations are quite ugly. Also I'm not entirely sure how to handle the types of actually storing the range and domain for the actual types.
- Use ad hoc type classes. So for every call you have to pass a record that has the appropriate implementations. This almost worked. It's a bit of a pain for the consumer of the API - and it goes somewhat against the grain of official advice as it encourages you to store functions and pass them around.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to define a single type of `Scale a` and each subclass of scale as a different constructor?

```elm
type Scale a
  = Continuous (Float, Float) (Float, Float)
  | Sequential (Float, Float) (Float -> a)
  | Quantile (List Float) (Float -> a)
```

`Sequential` and `Quantile` both require a type parameter while `Continuous` does not, so that's a bit ugly. Does it make sense to have a type parameter for `Continuous` for one of those values to make it a little cleaner?

If you're able to use a single type, then handling that type becomes a series of `case` statements.

```elm
convert : Scale a -> Float -> a
convert scale val =
  case scale of
    Continuous domain range -> ...
    Sequential domain mapper -> ...
    Quantile domain mapper -> ...
```

And instead of throwing runtime errors, could you change the function signatures to return `Maybe a` and return `Nothing` on unsupported operations? While you wouldn't be able to determine support prior to a function call, you would at least have to explicitly handle a `Nothing` value being returned, and that ends up being the way to check for support after the fact.

```elm
invertExtent : Scale a -> a -> Maybe (Float, Float)
invertExtent scale val =
  case scale of
    Continuous _ _ -> Nothing
    Sequential _ _ -> Nothing
    Quantile domain mapper -> Just (...)
```

Comment: I think requiring `Maybe` for all results of operation for what is principally a type-level concern is quite ugly. What I mean is that the only reason such a call might fail is passing in the wrong "type" of scale. It is also not trivial for the caller to handle the maybe as there is not necessarily a sensible default value.

Answer (score 2):

*I consider this an extension of Chad's answer, that takes into account the comment you made on it.*

You're certainly right that liberal use of `Maybe`s should indicate a design problem. Taking it one step further, though, it seems as though you are trying very hard to combine logically distinct ideas. The design that seems to fit best within the Elm ecosystem would actually be to keep these things separate at the API level.

**Consider `Result`, `Maybe`, and `Task`.** They provide similar functions, and thus, they provide very similar interfaces (i.e. `map` and `andThen`). There is a very obvious way to convert between them, but there is no polymorphism since they are actually different ideas with **different use cases**.

I think that is the key: use type unions when you have the same thing with multiple expressions. If you are not certain, just make multiple types. It's very easy to collapse this sort of stuff later since elm's compiler is so helpful and thorough!

---

**EDIT:** Here's a stab at an implementation that delays unification: https://gist.github.com/hkgumbs/069437f3e6b75ea15201b36188f6cc7a

Comment: I do however have a use case for unifying these. In this case for example I have an `axis : Scale -> Svg msg`. I could make a zillion versions of these as well (i.e. axisLinear, axisQuantile, etc.), but for the consumer, a scale is mostly the same concept. By far the most common use is using the `convert` function.

Comment: Right, keeping things separate doesn't preclude you from having a `toScale` function in each of those. _OR_, what I might do in that case is have a `Scale` type that unifies the other distinct types and implement `axis` in there. I'll admit, I don't fully understand what you're trying to model, but I've taken a stab at an implementation in the new link at the end of my answer. The basic idea is still "keep most of the things separate." Save the unifying until you are absolutely sure that they are _in essence_ the same "thing."

Comment: I apologise for not being too clear, but SO only encourages questions of a *reasonable* length and the problem domain here is quite complex. I suspect that unifying before calling methods would be annoying, since only some methods can be called on some subsets of the "types". So you would need to have different unification methods for different target methods. So you would end up having `toConvertable` and `toInvertable` and so on. It wouldn't necessarily simplify writing the client components either, since it would be quite difficult to write their type signature.

Comment: For illustration, this https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/0t2h282n3y3p0J0A330f/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-25%20at%2017.42.31.png?v=19ec95bc is the matrix of supported operations and types in the domain. (This is not essential, but it might help appreciate the fact that there are things that are shared and things that are not).

Comment: _This seems like the conversation that is best had over chat, but I don't think I'm able to do that without the link popping up._ Are all of these columns interoperable / convertible? Assuming not, I stand by my suggestion to keep these things separate and reflect the similarities by presenting similar APIs.